# I want to create sub query in stored proc in oracle the following query giving error too many values

Tags: oracle11g

I want to add this query in stored procedure but it gives an error: `ORA-00913: too many values`

```sql
Select SUM(CONNMASS.CONN_BILLAMOUNT) as Revenuebilled, 
       count(CONNMASS.CONN_BILLEDUNITS) AS volumebilled,
       count(MASSBILL.BM_lo_id) as normalbilled,
       ( SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN SRM_DISCON_STATUS_ID = 3 THEN 1 END) AS ACTIVE_CONNECTIONS,
                COUNT(CASE WHEN SRM_DISCON_STATUS_ID = 2 THEN 1 END) AS DISC_CONNECTIONS
         from Connection_master)
from   CONNECTION_MASTER CONNMASS
       left join BILLING_MASTER MASSBILL
       on MASSBILL.CONN_SERVICE_NO = CONNMASS.CONN_SERVICE_NO;
```

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
What have you done to identify and solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are selecting multiple values in the sub-query. You can only select a single value in a sub-query in the `SELECT` clause.

However, you do not need the sub-query and appear to want:

```sql
Select SUM(CONNMASS.CONN_BILLAMOUNT) as Revenuebilled, 
       count(CONNMASS.CONN_BILLEDUNITS) AS volumebilled,
       count(MASSBILL.BM_lo_id) as normalbilled,
       COUNT(CASE SRM_DISCON_STATUS_ID WHEN 3 THEN 1 END) AS ACTIVE_CONNECTIONS,
       COUNT(CASE SRM_DISCON_STATUS_ID WHEN 2 THEN 1 END) AS DISC_CONNECTIONS
from   CONNECTION_MASTER CONNMASS
       left join BILLING_MASTER MASSBILL
       on MASSBILL.CONN_SERVICE_NO = CONNMASS.CONN_SERVICE_NO;
```

If you did want the sub-queries then:

```sql
Select SUM(CONNMASS.CONN_BILLAMOUNT) as Revenuebilled, 
       count(CONNMASS.CONN_BILLEDUNITS) AS volumebilled,
       count(MASSBILL.BM_lo_id) as normalbilled,
       ( SELECT COUNT(CASE SRM_DISCON_STATUS_ID WHEN 3 THEN 1 END)
         from Connection_master) AS ACTIVE_CONNECTIONS,
       ( SELECT COUNT(CASE SRM_DISCON_STATUS_ID WHEN 2 THEN 1 END)
         from Connection_master) AS DISC_CONNECTIONS
from   CONNECTION_MASTER CONNMASS
       left join BILLING_MASTER MASSBILL
       on MASSBILL.CONN_SERVICE_NO = CONNMASS.CONN_SERVICE_NO;
```